# Regex for 'input' in a css rule

Tags: regex, css-selectors

I'm trying to filter input selectors (with javascript) from any CSS rules in a stylesheet but can't write a regex that returns all elements in that rule. I'm fine on the javascript but I'm not sure how to build the right regex.

For example, from the following:

```
input, #testDiv input, div.test, input[type=radio] {
    width: 50px;
}
```

I need to return `input`, `#testDiv input` and `input[type=radio]` if at all possible (or something close that I can trim down).

Can anyone who knows their regEx's give me some insight on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each line of CSS file try this regexp:

```
r = new RegExp('[^,}]*input[^,{]*', 'g')
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8DRMz/1/

How it works:

Selector with `input` can contains different symbols, but new selector always starts with newline, after "," or after "}". Also selector always ends with "," or "{". So we seeking "input" with any prepended symbols except ",}" and any appended symbols except ",{".